# Converting 'error' events to local exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, error-handling, event-handling

I'm using Node.JS and an event-based API (serialport) that provides `error` events, and I'd like to handle errors by throwing exceptions on the spot. I understand that this means I need to do things in a more synchronous manner.

However, I'm having trouble finding a direct way to do this. The only way I've figured out how to do it is by using an intermediate promise along with `async`/`await`, like this example of opening a serial port (which works but seems roundabout):

```
import { SerialPort } from 'serialport';
import assert from 'node:assert';

// return port on success, throw something on error
async function openPort (path) {
    const p = new SerialPort({path:path,baudRate:9600});
    return await new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
        p.once('open', () => resolve(p));
        p.once('error', e => reject(e));
    }).catch(e => {
        throw e;
    });
}

// synchronously open the port and handle resulting exception
let port;
try {
    port = await openPort('INVALIDPATH');
    assert(port);
    assert(port.port);
    assert(port.port.isOpen);
    console.log('port open');
} catch (e) {
    console.log('failed:', e);
}

// continue doing other stuff (errors are not fatal)
console.log('continuing to do other stuff...');
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a more direct way to cause `error` events to throw exceptions when the event is handled?
2. Is there a way to do the above but *not* have to use `await` when calling `openPort()`?

---

As a side note I think I see a bug in the above code where the `once('error',...)` event handler will stay attached on successful open, so if an error occurs later it'll go back and call that stale event handler. I'd like to avoid this, because there's other `error` events that may occur later that I'm going to want to handle as well.

Comment: Promises are fine here, IMO. There are many different ways to go, but it's not clear to me what exactly bothers you about your code. If you just find you code cumbersome, try to extract event handler functions into named local functions and play around and see where it leads you. -- You _will_ need either `await`s or [nesting of callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing#callbacks), which is both fine. -- There are ways to write utility functions if appropriate, like converting an array into sequential function calls.